# Is an email a "written request"?

Tags: hoa

In Florida, HOAs are required to provide records to owners.   Owners must provide a written request for.  Is an email to the hired record keeper a written request?

Update: Assume for the exercise that recipient replies to the message indicating that the message is read.

Comment: Can you prove the record keeper actually read the email request?  They might say it went to their Spam/Junk folder.....

Comment: @abelenky the law doesn’t require recipients to read stuff, only to receive it. Email in a spam/junk folder has been legally received.

Comment: Generally speaking emails count as signed writings subject to more specific statutory provisions.

Answer (score 1):

Although [Florida law](http://www.leg.state.fl.us/statutes/index.cfm?App_mode=Display_Statute&URL=0700-0799/0720/Sections/0720.303.html) simply says that records

> shall be made available to a parcel owner.. within 10 business days
>   after receipt by the board or its designee of a written request

what else you may want to know is that

> The failure of an association to provide access to the records within
>   10 business days *after receipt of a written request submitted by
>   certified mail, return receipt requested*, creates a rebuttable
>   presumption that the association willfully failed to comply with this
>   subsection.

The teeth in the record law is/are that

> A member who is denied access to official records is entitled to the
>   actual damages or minimum damages for the association’s *willful
>   failure* to comply with this subsection.

Technically, email constitutes a written request, but there is no penalty for failing to comply with a written request, there is a penalty for failing to timely comply with a written request submitted by certified mail, return receipt requested.

Answer (score 0):

### Yes

So is a text message or Facebook or Whatsapp post.

However, strange and different rules of service (i.e. when and how they have legal effect) may apply to different methods.

Comment: Please consider adding a reference \ precedent to support the answer?